# Can a String be used to store more than 1 input

Tags: java, string

How come the `String eingabe;` can be used first to save for int `m` and then for int `n`. I thought Strings, once declared can only be used to hold information for another method. Or does it store both values like "next to each other" and when told to print into console it takes out the value that is needed?

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int m, n, r;
    String eingabe;
    eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben sie ganze Zahl fuer m ein: ");
    m = Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
    eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl für n ein: ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
    r = m%n;

    while (r > 0) {
        m = n;
        n = r;
        r = m % n;
    }
    System.out.println("ggT = " + n);

    }


}
```

Comment: Which language do you write (probably Java)? What is wrong with the code? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: Yes it's Java. Well the code works the problem is I'm not sure why `String eingabe` can be used to save more than 1 Input

Comment: `eingabe` is a variable. Variable stores the value of RHS of `=` sign. when you assign a new value to a variable, it forgets the old one and stores the new one. you can assign a new value to it many many times, but each time, the old one will be forgotten.

Comment: first you set `eingabe` to the value from the first dialogue and get the int. then you overwrite it with the value from the second dialogue and get the int. No, a reference doesn't hold more than one value at the time but can have different values at different times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String variable eingabe is not being used to store more than one input. Following the line

```
 eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben sie ganze Zahl fuer m ein: ");
```

**eingabe** is a reference to whatever value you will parse into the int **m**. Following that on the line

```
 eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl für n ein: ");
```

The reference will be reassigned to point to the new String value you have got from **showInputDialog**.

There is nothing odd going on here. The value that **eingabe** references has just been changed. You might be getting confused about Strings being immutable in Java. This is a different concept, as it means that a String instance can never be changed. However no String instances are being changed here, just a reference variable pointing to a different string.

To summarise, **eingabe** is a reference which at different points in the code is pointing to a different String in memory. It is never at any point holding a reference to two strings.